# Tesseract OCR Not Outputting Files

Tags: tesseract

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR>tesseract C:\wamp64\www\test.jpg C:\wamp64\www\test pdf
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v4.0.0.20181030 with Leptonica
Warning: Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead.
Estimating resolution as 279
```

That's my code. No file is made. I don't know what is happening with this code.

I'm in the directory as Tesseract-OCR (C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR), the location of the image to OCR is C:\wamp64\www\test.jpg, and the directory to output is C:\wamp64\www\test.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give dpi along with the image. If you go to metadata of the image, you won't find dpi and that's the reason you are getting a warning.

Try using:

- tesseract C:\wamp64\www\test.jpg C:\wamp64\www\test pdf --dpi 96
- tesseract C:\wamp64\www\test.jpg C:\wamp64\www\test pdf --dpi 279